# Why isn't return breaking out of this function?

Tags: javascript

While doing challenges on coderbyte i found someone else's solution. his code however was not working for 1 of the test cases, but i don't understand why.

challenge info: input is an array of 2 strings the first string contains 2 numbers representing the weights on both sides of a scale. the second string contains the weights u can use to try and balance the scale. goal: balance the scale with the least amount of weights (max 2) and output what weights you used.

the code outputs 1,6 which does balance the scale but the scale could also have been balanced by just one weight, 5. why doesn't the first "return" break out of the function?

```
function ScaleBalancing(strArr) {
    const w1 = JSON.parse(strArr[0])[0];
    const w2 = JSON.parse(strArr[0])[1];
    let weights = JSON.parse(strArr[1]);
    for (let i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        if (w1 + weights[i] === w2 || w2 + weights[i] === w1) {         
            return '' + weights[i]; // should return 5 and break out of function right?
        }
        //if this for loop is omitted the function returns 5
        for (let j = i + 1; j < weights.length; j++) {
            if (w1 + weights[i] + weights[j] === w2 ||
                w2 + weights[i] + weights[j] === w1 ||
                w1 + weights[i] === w2 + weights[j] ||
                w2 + weights[i] === w1 + weights[j]) {
                return '' + weights[i] + ',' + weights[j]; //this returns 1,6
            }
        }
    }
    return 'not possible';
}
// keep this function call here 
ScaleBalancing(["[6, 1]", "[1, 10, 6, 5]"]);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: There's no (apparent) reason to use JSON *strings* instead of simple array literals.

Comment: The reason is because `1` comes before `5` in the array.

Comment: Because the inner for-loop is run every loop the outer for-loop makes.

Comment: for the input w1=6 w2=1 and weights[0] as 1 the condition (w1 + weights[i] === w2 || w2 + weights[i] === w1) is false and the second for loops does its work and returns and exists from the function as expected.

Comment: @MaheerAli & SaniSinghHuttunen & PDKPavanKumar you guys are all right! very logical, i just didnt see it... thanks for your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the is that the outer loop starts from `0` index. On that point the code don't know that `5` will come sometime in array.

For the first number which is `1` the condition `(w1 + weights[i] === w2 || w2 + weights[i] === w1)` is `false` so it goes to nested `for` loop.

If you put `5` before `1` the code will return `5`

```js
function ScaleBalancing(strArr) {
    const w1 = JSON.parse(strArr[0])[0];
    const w2 = JSON.parse(strArr[0])[1];
    let weights = JSON.parse(strArr[1]);
    for (let i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        if (w1 + weights[i] === w2 || w2 + weights[i] === w1) {         
            return '' + weights[i]; // should return 5 and break out of function right?
        }
        //if this for loop is omitted the function returns 5
        for (let j = i + 1; j < weights.length; j++) {
            if (w1 + weights[i] + weights[j] === w2 ||
                w2 + weights[i] + weights[j] === w1 ||
                w1 + weights[i] === w2 + weights[j] ||
                w2 + weights[i] === w1 + weights[j]) {
                return '' + weights[i] + ',' + weights[j]; //this returns 1,6
            }
        }
    }
    return 'not possible';
}
// keep this function call here 
console.log(ScaleBalancing(["[6, 1]", "[5, 10, 6, 1]"]));
```

Comment: ofcourse!! *facepalm* thank you! very clear explaination. so to get this code working i could move the inner for loop outside of the first for loop right?

Comment: Just remove remove the first `if` condition if the loop. And before the main loop(outer one). Check for `w2.includes(Math.abs(w1[0] - w2[1]))`. If this returns true then return `Math.abs(w1[0] - w2[1])`